# In ipython notebook, how can I achieve a "single cell" style that hides all source code and edit buttons?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've just watched the pycon 2014 keynote by Fernando Pérez

He mentions that ipython notebook can have "non-notebook looking", "single cell" style, see the snapshot below or watch it in in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NSbuKFYyvc, at around 25:22

[image]

However after 30 minutes of googling, I can't find any resources related to this feature.

Anyone can help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fernando's example appears to come directly from minrk's repository on git hub.  The code is include there in full, although the documentation is rather thin.

I was able to get this running on my Windows 7 PC using IPython 2.0 and executing the following commands from a command window:

```
git clone https://github.com/minrk/singlecell.git
cd singlecell
python singlecell.py
```

These commands start a Tornado server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.  Open the application in a browser by typing that URL in the address address bar.  I saw exactly what Fernando showed on screen in his demo.

I hope that helps - you should be able to figure it out in detail by studying the code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the title one but can be simulate the same by the following commands.

```
1) upgrade to ipython 2.0
2) install ipython slideshow support(availble in ipython git repo)
3) slider control from from => IPython.html.widgets import interactive
```